# Zend Framework2 - Problemas com AbstractHelper

Tags: php, zend

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com problemas para exibir o nome do usuário logado usando view helper.

Module:

```
public function getViewHelperConfig() {
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'UserIdentity' => new View\Helper\UserIdentity()
        )
    );
}
```

UserIdentity:

```
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService,
    Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session as SessionStorage;

class UserIdentity extends AbstractHelper {

    protected $authService;

    public function getAuthService() {
        return $this->authService;
    }

    public function __invoke($namespace = null) {
        $sessionStorage = new SessionStorage($namespace);
        $this->authService = new AuthenticationService;
        $this->authService->setStorage($sessionStorage);

        if ($this->getAuthService()->hasIdentity()) {
            return $this->getAuthService()->getIdentity();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

View:

```
$usuario = $this->UserIdentity('Usuario');
```

Answer (score 0):

A configuração do seu plugin está incorreta. Ao invés de instanciar o seu helper, defina-o da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

namespace Application;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ViewHelperProviderInterface;

class Module implements ViewHelperProviderInterface
{

  public function getViewHelperConfig() {
    return array(
      'invokables' => array(
        'UserIdentity' => 'Application\View\Helper\UserIdentity'
      )
    );
  }

}
```

Também confira a consistência dos seus namespaces.

Espero ter ajudado! :D